# Pictorial puzzle

Tags: geometry, tiling

Can someone suggest a pictorial representation of a mathematical puzzle or problem that could be represented in coloured tiles on an orangery floor $4489\times7525$mm with an insert of $907 \times1996$ for steps  This has to be assembled so simple but complex is preferred

Comment: It's probably too late, but: what do you mean by 'an insert 907x1966'?  Do you mean that your individual tiles are that size (so that your total space is roughly 4x3 'pixels'), or that tiles will be roughly 4x3 mm so that you'll have an approximately 900x2000 grid of them?

Comment: How large is each tile?

Answer (score 1):

A [Penrose tiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_tiling) is a must. But there is a copyright on them if I remember well.

Nice to ask !

Comment: The patent on Penrose tiles was filed in 1979 and has long since expired.

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of ama's answer, the [Pinwheel tiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinwheel_tiling) is a very good choice.

Here is how it looks on the Federation Building: [image: Federation Building] [image: Federation Building].

The reason I like this more than many other tilings is because the basic tiles are easy to get: You pick a square tiling, split it into two equal rectangles, and then divide each rectangle by a diagonal (or the other for the reflected tile).

Answer (score 0):

An apollonian gasket could be fun, but it might be difficult to get your hands on suitable tiles. A variant of the Sierpinski carpet would be easier, though less aesthetically pleasing.

If you're using tiles small enough to draw smooth curves, I think a table of knots might be cool. Or you could split the floor up into 17 sections and fill each one with a representation of the wallpaper groups.